# Is there a way to include different angles of a symbol in the legend in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I wanted to plot DT where lag was represented by different arrow angles, how can I show this in a legend?

```
DT <- data.table(station=c(rep("station1",12),
                           rep("station2",12),
                           rep("station3",12)),
                 month=c(1:12),
                 lag=c(sample(0:2),replace=T))

ggplot() + geom_text(data=DT, 
                     aes(x=month,y=station,
                         angle=lag*45+90,
                         label="\U2192"))
```

[image: lag_plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for. But one way to achieve the desired result is via manipulating the legend keys via the `gtable`:

1. To get a legend we have to map `lag` on an aesthetic like e.g. `color`
2. Making use of `scale_color_manual` we can set the colors to `black`
3. Adjust the angle and the label of the legend key

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)

DT <- data.frame(station=c(rep("station1",12),
                           rep("station2",12),
                           rep("station3",12)),
                 month=c(1:12),
                 lag=c(sample(0:2),replace=T))

DT$angle <- DT$lag * 45 + 90

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_text(data =DT, 
            aes(x=month, y=station,
                angle = angle,
                color = factor(lag),
                label = "\U2192")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep("black", length(unique(DT$lag))))

# Get gtable
gt <- ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(ggplot2::ggplot_build(p))

# Get indices for guide box and legend keys
idx_guide_box <- which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")
idx_keys <- which(stringr::str_detect(gt$grobs[[idx_guide_box]]$grobs[[1]]$layout$name, "^key[\\-\\d]+$"))

for (i in seq_along(idx_keys)) {
  angle <- (i - 1) * 45 + 90
  idx_grob <- idx_keys[[i]]
  # Set angle and label
  gt$grobs[[idx_guide_box]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[idx_grob]]$rot <- angle
  gt$grobs[[idx_guide_box]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[idx_grob]]$label <- "\U2192"
}
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This does solve my problem. Is there a way to do this without using colour? I experimented with your code and if I removed colour, then the "guide box" did not exist within the gtable.

Comment: @someonesomeo Yes. Of course can we do without color. See my edit. It's just to get a legend (as you figured out yourself: Without using the color aes there is no guide-box.) Life were much easier if `angle` itself had a scale. However, except for text or symbols this probably wouldn't make much sense. (;